# iPhone Application Name Availability

Tags: iphone, naming

Is there a way to check whether an iphone application name is available to use? Would a search on iTunes and checking to see if there is an existing application already out there be indicative that an iphone application name is available to use or not?

Comment: Why is this being down-voted?  It's a legitimate question.  I'm interested in the answer as well.

Comment: not sure I understand why I got down voted either. I indicated that this was not programming related

Comment: This is a site for programming-related questions, so you're getting downvoted for being (knowingly) off topic.

Comment: +1, programming related, NPR tag removed.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry I did not realize - I'll take the question somewhere else. But i figured it was Okay since there is a not-programming-related tag with over 1000 questions in it.

Comment: lol @WillF - There are over 1000 NPR questions because (pick your answer):
a. There have been over 1000 instances where individuals did not read the FAQ.
b. There have been over 1000 instances where individuals thought their NPR question was important enough to ask on a programming website that goes out of its way to define itself as such.
c. There are sweaty-toothed, self-appointed protectors of SO who fiercely defend the site's integrity by immediately downvoting, retagging, and voting to close any question they interpret as being not related to programming.
d. All of the above.

Comment: @WillF, I mean no disrespect, btw.  I just think it's funny and ironic that you saw how many NPR questions have been tagged as such and thought that gave you the go ahead to ask away.  I also think your question is certainly programming related.

Comment: To me, this looks peripherally programming-related.  It doesn't meet my personal criterion (would it be equally at home in a similar website for accountants?) for NPR, so I'm not voting to close.

Comment: @ScottieT +1 because I kept reading National Public Radio questions and it made me laugh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [pointed out here](http://carpeaqua.com/2009/04/11/appstore-stake-your-claim/), even if you search the traditional channels, there may still be someone who has claimed that same name but not submitted an application yet.  If you wish to truly test this out, it sounds like you can start the process of submitting an application on iTunes Connect, fill in the name of your new application, but don't complete the submission.  You should receive an indication as to whether someone else has this same store name.  If not, it appears you now have a claim to that name.

In any case, because you can have a different name in the store than is displayed on the iPhone, you might be able to use a slight permutation on the name for your store submission, and your desired name within the iPhone application itself.

However, I would second sgmeyer's suggestion that you do a USPTO trademark search first before using a name.  Trademark infringement can get you in trouble later on.

Comment: I can confirm that searching the application store isn't adequate. I just discovered a name conflict last night which a search didn't reveal. We had to redo artwork, a website, etc.

Comment: Leaving out info in the submission no longer works as it greys out the submit button if you do.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend searching the app store for the name you wish to use.  Also, you might want to check the United States Patent and Trademark Office [www.uspto.gov/](http://www.uspto.gov/) to ensure there isn't a trade mark that exists on the name you choose.

Answer (score 2):

You must search from iTunes Connect as if you are adding a new app, just searching on Google doesn't show app names that are alreadcoques iphone 4

Answer (score -3):

Search the app store, and search google.

Answer (score -3):

I'd say if the name you want to use doesn't turn up in a search on iTunes, you should be in the clear to grab that name.  I assume all app names are subject to approval by Apple, also, so make sure you pick something that's not called "iBabyShake."

Comment: You must search from iTunes Connect as if you are adding a new app, just searching on Google doesn't show app names that are already reserved by other developers.

Comment: @Scottie T, I mean no disrespect, I just think it's funny and ironic that you would be so harsh in your comment to the OP above then pose an answer such as this that offers absolutely no insight whatsoever and ultimately all but says "hmm, you know I'm not sure but here's some unsubstantiated advice"