# App Store and iTunes connect: Safeguarding App name before release

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I am about to publish the name of my App on Kickstarter. I am worried that someone will copy the name and publish an app with the same name before I release mine.

Is there a way to block this? I heard that if I create an App bundle on iTunes Connect prior to release I should be able to block this. From my understanding, starting from the moment in which I create the App in the iTunes connect profile **I will have a window of 4 months of time to publish it** and, if someone attempts to use the same name, won't be able to do so.

Is my understanding correct? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757126/availability-of-a-name-for-an-app-in-the-appstore) and seems that is the case but there is no mention on the 4 months window.

Answer (score 4):

According to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html you have 180 days to submit a binary after registering the app name in itunesconnect.

Comment: What's really important and not made that obvious is that after this time runs out you won't be able to use that app name again.

Answer (score 4):

I have personally experienced this: I started work on an app, set it up in iTunes Connect (in order to test Game Center), then had to put it on hold. I started getting warning emails from Apple (that the app entry was about to expire and I'd lose the name) and I chose to put something out in the store, since it wasn't clear what would happen if I simply deleted it from iTunes Connect.

If you're really worried about this, you probably need to find a legal solution, not a technological one. I'm not a lawyer, and this is a site about programming, but I think you should look into trademark law. It is the part of the law that covers names and claiming who has the rights to them. If you follow the law and claim a name, you may be able to get it back from someone who takes it.

You could also NOT reveal the name on Kickstarter, but use a code name instead, and then avoid this problem entirely.

To be perfectly honest, I don't think this will be as much as a problem as you think it will be.

Comment: He could just upload a binary that for sure would be rejected. Just use some private API with a terrible UI that really doesn't do anything but collect user data and send it to some server. Don't forget to use the UDID!

Comment: Or you can upload a binary but set a manual release date WAY into the future.

Comment: As benzado hinted at, safeguarding the use of the app name in the App Store is only one step in safeguarding the name. You should post a ™ symbol next to the name on any website or printed matter. Later, if you successfully register it, you'll get to replace ™ with ®. You also should do a trademark search at the [USPTO](http://uspto.gov) website to ensure that no one else has already trademarked the name for similar products or services. If it's a generic name, you can't trademark it anyway, so the app name is all you have to worry about.

Comment: I have registered a UK trademark for my App name and hence, according to the trademark law, I should be able to use the registered symbol ®. Thanks for all the useful advice.